# NGINX - axios GET request returning the VUE.js index.html file for all static html files i'm trying to fetch via get requests

Tags: nginx, centos

So, I have a vue app that's working well on my MAC running `npm run serve`.

Running `npm run build` and deploy my code to my CENTOS environment (using NGINX) all of the .get requests are coming back are returning a 200 in the network tab, but the content should be a static html file that i'm pulling into my app.

here are some code samples:

```
this.axios.get(flatHtmlLocation).then(response => {
                let corsHTML = response.data;
                let htmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(corsHTML, "text/html");
                this.rawDog = htmlDoc;
                this.htmlData = htmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
            })
```

^ this works just fine when I'm playing around on my Mac.

I'm pulling my static .html files from the /public/ directory in a specific directory.

Here is what my file structure looks like:

name of app

```
-- public
     index.html
     /directory-where-static-html-lives/filename.html 
  -- src
     -- components/component/file_pulling_the_static_asset.vue
```

Here is a copy of my .conf (NGINX) file for the app in prod that I'm using:

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    server_name _;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://some-fancy-pants-url:4000;
    }
 location /public/ {
        root /opt/location-of-my-app;
    }

    location / {
        root    /opt/location-of-my-app/dist;
        index    index.html index.htm;
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }



}
```

I have screen shots, but ServerFault won't let me post them BeCAusE RePuTaTiOn!

TLDR: When I do a `GET` request in the UI and try to `GET` `/opt/location-of-my-app/dist/someDirectoryName/subDirectory/nameOfFile.html`,  the page that is actually returned with a `200 success` is: `/opt/location-of-my-app/dist/index.html`.

What am I doing wrong in my NGIX .conf file that is causing this to happen?

Comment: What was the URL you requested, then?

Comment: ok - `http://myurl.com/someDirectoryName/subDirectory/nameOfFile.html` - and then the contents of that file are always the contents of `/opt/location-of-my-app/dist/index.html`. I've got some screen shots showing the paths and the return values, but i don't have enough clout to post here.

Comment: Does the file actually exist and is readable in your filesystem at that location?

Comment: jake, did you solve it? I am facing the same thing..

Answer (score 0):

For `/public` you still need to add a `try_files` drective.

Try this

```
    ...

    location /public {
        root /opt/location-of-my-app;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    ...
```